# redirect_uri_mismatch Unity Google API on iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, unity-game-engine, oauth-2.0, google-play-services

I created an app in Unity with Google Play Leaderboard support. I could easily make it work on Android, then I moved to OSX to build it for iPhone too. 
First I got a problem, that Apple won't accept any bundle identifier with the '_' character in it, but my Android app bundle identifier had 2 of them...
However I found out, that in the Google Developer Console I can link another app to my app (to use the same Leaderboard) for iOS too, so I was quite happy. Unfortunately this doesn't seem to work. I get the *redirect_uri_mismatch* error message every time I try to log in.

On Android I used the [UnityGPGPlugin](https://github.com/faizann/UnityGPGPlugin) but as it didn't work for me on iOS, I tried the [PlayGameServices](https://github.com/playgameservices/play-games-plugin-for-unity) too. In UnityGPGPlugin I could set only the Application ID, so I thought that's why it is not working. In the PlayGameServices plugin there are two fields, one for the Application ID and one for the Client ID that made it look like that's really what I need. Unfortunately the error is still present and I really don't know what I could do with it. Here is the well known message:

```
Error: redirect_uri_mismatch

Request Details
cookie_policy_enforce=false
scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/appstate 
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/games 
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login 
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.moments.write 
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me 
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.profile.agerange.read 
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.profile.language.read 
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.circles.members.read
response_type=code
access_type=offline
redirect_uri= < my bundle identifier without '_' characters >:/oauth2callback
state=16885367
gpsdk=1.5.0
verifier=12647966
display=page
client_id=123456789123-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com
hl=en
```

The debug log contains only this:

```
2014-03-16 14:21:19.507 <my app>[1699:60b] GPGSAuthenticateWithCallback.
2014-03-16 14:21:19.509 <my app>[1699:60b] GPGSManager initializing and authenticating.
2014-03-16 14:21:19.512 <my app>[1699:60b] GPPSignIn initialized.
2014-03-16 14:21:19.514 <my app>[1699:60b] GPPSignIn attempting sign in now.
-> applicationWillResignActive()
-> applicationDidEnterBackground()
```

Does anyone know how could I solve this problem?
Thanks in advance!

Edit:
Maybe it wasn't obvious, but I have 2 bundle identifiers, both of them are linked to the same game service in Google Play Developer Console. The com.x.a_b_c belongs to the Android app, the com.x.abc belongs to the iOS app.

Answer (score 0):

I was having redirect_uri_mismatch error while using UnityGPGPlugin. I was using "123456789123" as my Application ID instead of "123456789123-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx".

However, I manage to get through the Google Sign In page after changing all my setup to "123456789123-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" as my Application ID. Including the GPGApplicationID in Info.plist.

Sad to say that I am having another problem now, but at least that's how I manage to get through that error. :)

Comment: Thanks for the tip, although I guess I already tried that before (I'm not sure).
Unfortunately I can't test it anymore because I simply moved to the Game Center, so I keep using GPG on Android but makes more sense to use the Game Center on iOS.
And now I don't know if I should accept it as an answer :)

Comment: i moved to Game Center on iOS and kept GPG on Android too. :) my previous problem was the app is not detecting user login status. and i chose to switch to Game Center instead of wasting more time in solving the problem. :) Good luck to you! :D